# i was trying build my android project but i face an error :

Tags: android

Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 17 declared in library [pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.22] C:\Users\hp.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\fc810e6524b0417884f22eea64b8e3c7\jetified-android-gif-drawable-1.2.22\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 16
> Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 16,
> or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 17,
> or use tools:overrideLibrary="pl.droidsonroids.gif" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)

This is the problem which i face while building

Comment: There is a library you added in your project that has a minimum sdk of 17 and your project has a minimum sdk of 16 , so make your projects' minimum sdk to 17 or remove the dependency of the library

Answer (score 0):

To change the minimum SDk of your project go to
1- build.gradle (app Module)
2- look for the android block that should look something like this

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.yourproject.blabla"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
        dexOptions{
            preDexLibraries = false
        }
```

3- change the mindSdkVersion to 17 and try to build the project